# nvd3 - multiBarChart: how to log scale y axis

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

According the [multiBarChart doc](http://nvd3-community.github.io/nvd3/examples/documentation.html#multiBarChart) it should be possible to set yScale on multiBarChart as yScale should be inherited method.

I'd like to scale it to logarithmic scale. I got this working with `lineChart.yScale(d3.scale.log())`, but for multiBarChart, calling `multiBarChart.yScale(d3.scale.log())`, results in `yScale is not a function`.

Is there any other way to log scale multiBarChart's y axis?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this whit following approach, it's controlled by `shouldLogScale` var:

```
nv.addGraph(() => {
  this.chart = nv.models.multiBarChart()
    ...
    .y(d => {
      const y = parseFloat(d.y);
      return this.shouldLogScale ? Math.log10(y <= 0 ? 1 : y) : y;
    });

  if(this.shouldLogScale) {
    this.logScale();
  } else {
    this.chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(`,.${this.precision}f`));
  }

  ...
});
```

When initialising the chart: I modify `y` values, force `y` (`chart.forceY`) start and end values (map them to their log10 [range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(mathematics))), analogically I set `chart.yAxis.tickValues`. Lastly I map ticks (`chart.yAxis.tickValues`) to their original values. Just make sure to comply [domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_a_function) of the log function.

`logScale` method:

```
private logScale() {
  this.chart.forceY([1, 180]
    .map(v => Math.log10(v)));
  this.chart.yAxis.tickValues([1, 3, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 180]
    .map(v => Math.log10(v)));
  this.chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d => Math.pow(10, d).toFixed(this.precision));
}
```

Maybe I could use a map of y domain and range values to avoid using log and pow functions in `logScale` method.